# Gatsby site looks and functions very differently on Firefox than other browsers - JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: firefox, gatsby, netlify

After having deployed my gatsby website with netlify, I realised that while it seems to work perfectly on other browsers, JavaScript seems to be disabled for the site on Firefox and google fonts does not seem to have worked as well. Anyone know why this could be? Highly appreciate any help!
[Site for Reference](https://jdit.netlify.com)

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my firefox browser. JS works for me. Maybe you have a script blocker addon enabled?

Comment: Comparing the firefox at home, the one at my work, as well as the one on my phone all give me issues (and I have not done configuration on any of them since I am not a firefox user) - the images using Gatsby Img tags do not load, missing google font for the logo, cannot search for posts on the archive page, etc. I also thought that firefox could be blocking my scripts, but if this is happening on a default installation of the browser it must be a bigger issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a regex with a lookbehind, so firefox disabled my JavaScript.